# Load more 10 items from API on click button in the list in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular15

I want to load 10 items every time click on the button.
Here is the services code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentDataService {

  url = "https://dummyjson.com/users?limit=10";

  // Constructor / Instance
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getdata(){
    return this.http.get(this.url)
  }
}
```

HTML/Bootstrap Code is here:
There is a button at the bottom you can see the load more. As I set the limit 10 in the API, but I need to load 10 more list every time on button click.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#ID</th>
      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Age</th>
      <th scope="col">Gender</th>
      <th scope="col">User Detail</th>
      <th scope="col">Add To Favorite</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of newdata.users">
      <td>{{ user?.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ user?.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user?.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user?.age }}</td>
      <td>{{ user?.gender }}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="UserClicked(user)">
          See Details
        </button>
      </td>
      <td (click)="moveToFavorite(user)">
        <button class="btn-fav">Add To Favorite</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="btn-div">

  <button class="load-more ">Load More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your "Load More" button, you should have a click event to load users.

```
<button class="load-more" (click)="loadUsers()">Load More</button>
```

You should have a variable to track the `limit`. When the `loadUsers` is called, the `limit` should be added by 10. And pass the `limit` to the `getData` in the `StudentDataService` service. Also you should update the `newData` when the observable is returned.

```
limit: number = 10;

loadUsers() {
  this.limit += 10;
  this.studentDataService.getdata(this.limit)
    .subscribe({
      next: (resp) => {
        this.newdata = resp;
      }
    })
}
```

In your `StudentDataService`, the `getdata` function should have an argument to receive the `limit` and pass it into the URL as the query string.

```
export class StudentDataService {

  url = "https://dummyjson.com/users";


  getdata(limit: number = 10) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + `?limit=${limit}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is giving me all the products at once on click the button.

Comment: Hi, are you providing the limit to the API URL?

Comment: Hi, please see this url ( https://ibb.co/s6k0ZNj ).

Comment: Can you share the `getdata` method? To confirm that it receives the value from the parameter and combine the value as query string.

Comment: Please see here in this image:  ( https://ibb.co/gSFvbsJ )

Comment: From your latest code, your query string is correct, missing `=`, it should be `?limit=${limit}`